# Unable to Publish from Github Desktop Application to github.com

Tags: github, keychain, git-commit, publishing

While trying to publish from Github desktop app to github.com am getting the following error.

> GitHub Desktop was unable to store the account token in the keychain.
>   Please check you have unlocked access to the 'login' keychain.

- relogin didnt help.
- Updating Github desktop didn't help.
- Deleted all the entries regarding github in Keychain tool

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the Keychain being in an invalid state, affecting applications that try to use the keychain to store or retrieve credentials. Seems to be specific to macOS High Sierra and Mojave.

Workaround:

- Open Keychain Access.app
- Right-click on the login keychain and try locking it
- Right-click on the login keychain and try unlocking it
- Sign into your GitHub account again

and it works like charm.

Comment: It save my 1 day! Thanks. It's really help me a lot.