# Not receiving Keychain prompt when I try to cache my Github username and password on OSX

Tags: git, macos, github, keychain

I like having my Github username and password cached so I don't have to enter my credentials every time I pull/push to Github. The first time I followed [instructions provided by Github](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/) and it worked great.

I then updated from Sierra to High Sierra and this caused the terminal to ask for my username and password once again. I follow Github's instructions to fix this but I don't get the prompt for Keychain Access to store my credentials the first time I push/pull to Github. I couldn't fix this so I eventually resorted to resetting my Keychain Access to default. This made it so that I was able to get the prompt and have my credentials cached.

I upgraded to Mojave and it won't even let me reset Keychain Access anymore. I try asking why this is the case [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/340890/reset-keychain-access-to-default-after-mojave-upgrade) but so far I haven't gotten any answers. This is my `.gitconfig` file when I type `git config --global --edit` in the terminal:

```
[user]
    email = [email]
    name = [name]
[core]
    editor = code --wait
    pager = cat
[format]
    pretty = oneline
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
```

`osxkeychain helper` is definitely installed. What am I doing wrong? How do I it to show the prompt for me to grant access to OSX keychain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before swithcing ti an SSH URL as a workaround, which would also avoid entering any credentials (easier if you have a passphrase-less private key), try first to unlock your key.

See [here as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52653016/6309), when opening your Keychain access.app.
See also "[How to Resolve Mac OS X Keychain Problems](https://help.queens.edu/hc/en-us/articles/205937040-How-to-Resolve-Mac-OS-X-Keychain-Problems)" for other options.

Comment: You are an absolute lifesaver! The first link did it for me. Thank you so much for this